# Swiss-pairing algorithm

Tags: software, swiss-pairing

Is there a (simple) algorithm for setting up a swiss tournament? I've searched around a little, but can't find anything specific.

Alternatively, is there any good and free software available for setting up swiss tournaments? All of those I've tried have very few options and little functionality available.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> is there any good and free software available for setting up swiss
> tournaments? All of those I've tried have very few options and little
> functionality available.

[Vega](http://www.vegachess.com/tl/index.php/Home_page_English.html) is a swiss pairing program which has been approved by FIDE. It is free if you install it on Linux and if you install it on Windows it is free up to 30 players in the tournament. It is a lot more user friendly than other programs you have to pay for and is excellent for amateur use.

The only drawbacks for professional use are the 30 player limit if used on Windows and the lack of a website for publishing the pairings and results. The program allows you to prepare HTML files for uploading to your own (or the tournament) website but it does not come with a standalone website like Chess-results.com which comes with Swiss Manager.
Since the first answer Vega has a publishing site https://www.vegaresult.com/

Answer (score 4):

As for tournaments with swiss system, many computer programs are paid. That's why I decided to create a freeware program (REALLY free). Name of my program is VinczeSwiss. The VinczeSwiss program is available for download at: http://vincze.euweb.cz or http://vinczeswiss.sweb.cz

Answer (score 2):

You can use Schachturnierorganisationsprogramm for Swiss-Tournaments. Since FIDE-Congress Abu Dhabi 2020 Schachturnierorganisationsprogramm is endorsed by the SPP-Commission. My program is open-source and free to use.

Available languages are: German, English, French, Spanish, Bavarian, Italian and Portuguese.

Download [here](https://www.freebasic-portal.de/downloads/anwendungssoftware/schachturnierorganisationsprogramm-233.html).